# gdal_merge.py can't find libgdal.so.20

Tags: gdal, gdal-merge, gdal-python-binding

I am having some trouble with GDAL (v2.1-dev).  I build it from source today using Poppler and OpenJPEG.  All the command line utilities work fine, but none of the Python plugins work at all, producing this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gdal_merge.py", line 37, in <module>
import gdal
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdal.py", line 2, in <module>
from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
_gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libgdal.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Now, I've seen plenty of threads that say update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or include `/usr/local/bin/` in my `ld.so.conf` file. I've done both of those things and they don't help.  Furthermore, those posts all refer to `libgdal.so.1` not being found. So, I added the location of `libgdal.so.20` to `ld.so.conf` and still no dice.

Any recommendations?

**Update (11/2/15)**
I am running Ubuntu 14.04.03 32bit, cleanly installed just a few days ago.
I [followed these instructions](http://wiki.wildsong.biz/index.php/Building_GDAL_on_Linux) to download, make, and install GDAL and OpenJPEG in a folder I made called /home/ronn4031/src/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you do `ldconfig` to be sure that your changes to LD_LIBRARY_PATH are really applied?

Where is your `libgdal.so.20` file?

Did you look at the GDAL [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/.travis.yml) file? A Travis file instructs how you can compile, deploy code for testing. It's firstly for testing code purpose but you can also use it to find out if you didn't miss a point when compiling.

**Edit**

It seems that you are missing parts otherwise, it would works.
You will find below what I tried to make things work on an Ubuntu box 14.04 (mainly extracted from the .travis.yml file)

```
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/etc-data.koordinates.com/gdal-travisci/install-openjpeg-2.0.0-ubuntu12.04-64bit.tar.gz
tar xzf install-openjpeg-2.0.0-ubuntu12.04-64bit.tar.gz
sudo cp -r install-openjpeg/include/* /usr/local/include
sudo cp -r install-openjpeg/lib/* /usr/local/lib

cd ~/$HOME
git clone https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal.git
cd gdal/gdal
./autogen.sh
# I use a prefix because I don't want to mix this compiled version with my already GDAL versions installed 
./configure --with-python --with-poppler --with-openjpeg=/usr/local --prefix=/usr/local/gdal
make
make install
ldconfig

# Temporary: you have to make them persistent or remove the prefix option in configure I used
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/gdal/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/gdal/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/gdal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Launch Python with `python` and do the following to try if it's working:

```
from osgeo import gdal
print gdal.VersionInfo() # Should return 2010000 currently (may change with time)
```

I also tried gdal_merge.py and it works too (the initial issue you raised)

Comment: Yes, I have run `ldconfig` so that it's properly updated.  My `libgdal.so.20' file is located in `/home/ronn4031/src/gdal/.libs/libgdal.so.20` and as for the `.travis.yml` I can't find it.  Suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Follow the link in my main answer by clicking on the text ".travis.yml"! For the `libgdal.so.20`, you should also have it in /usr/local/lib/ or /usr/lib and not only in `/home/ronn4031/src/gdal/.libs/libgdal.so.20` (it's the place before you make the `make install` not the definitive place normally).

Comment: Okay so I copied libgdal.so.20 into /usr/local/lib (where libgdal.so is and the directory definitely included in ld.so.conf) with no success, which didn't really surprise me. I followed the ".travis.yml" link right after I posed, realized it was a link.  I can't find it in my gdal folder with either `locate` or `ls -a`.  Why would that be?

Comment: You should avoid copying files like that without understanding the "why". It's not the way to deploy a compiled version (for GDAL at least). For the "missing" `.travis.yml`, the question is where did you download the code you are compiling?

Comment: I know I should understand why I am doing things, and I'm sure that was a bad practice but I was in a bind for time (working on a school project).  I was able to use `gdalwarp` to put my rasters together, though, so it's all good.  I downloaded the files to /home/ronn4031/src/ (folder I created) and [followed these instructions](http://wiki.wildsong.biz/index.php/Building_GDAL_on_Linux) to build and install.  Can you point me to any resources that might help me understand the best practice for building from source?

Comment: Congrats for achieving your goal. For learning about compilation on Linux, in general, go to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware

Comment: `ldconfig` was the missing step after installing `gdal` from source.. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with python 3.5.2 |Anaconda after installing via "conda install gdal". I searched for libgdal.so.20 on my computer, but it was nowhere. I then first did a "conda install libgdal" and then "conda install gdal". This fixed the problem for me.